# wxPython dialogs: "Enter" keyboard button would not "ok" the dialog

Tags: python, keyboard, wxpython

I am creating a custom wxPython dialog by subclassing `wx.Dialog`. When I press Enter while using it, (and while being focused on one of the form elements,) it just takes the focus to the next form element, while I want it to press the ok button.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should happen automatically if the button has the *wx.ID_OK* id. If that's impossible then the *wx.StdDialogButtonSizer.SetAffirmativeButton()* method could be a solution (using the *StdDialogButtonSizer* class will help with correct button placement and positioning on the different platforms), and there is also *wx.Button.SetDefault()*.

Comment: I put the id as wx.ID_OK, didn't seem to affect anything. I looked for SetAffirmativeButton (in Dialog), doesn't seem to exist. There is SetAffirmativeId, tried it on the button's ID, and it didn't work.

Comment: For best conformance to different platforms' UI guidelines you should use wx.StdDialogButtonSizer which has that method; see http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StdDialogButtonSizer-class.html

Comment: There is also wx.Button.SetDefault()... Anyway, what platform are you on, and what other controls are in the dialog?

Comment: XP, but it should work on them all.

The other controls are RadioButtons and TextCtrls.

Going to sleep now, will try your solutions tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: button.SetDefault() is what you want.

Comment: I tried everything listed here, and the only thing that worked for me was `button.SetDefault()`